# Vectorized computation of new pandas column using only hour-of-date from existing dates column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

What I have:

- A pandas dataframe with a column containing dates
- Python 3.6

What I want:

- Compute a new column, where the new value for every row depends only on a part of the date in the existing column for the same row (for example, an operation that depends only on the hour of the date)
- Do so in an efficient manner (thinking, vectorized), as opposed to row-by-row computations.

---

**Example dataframe** (small dataframe is convenient for printing, but I also have an actual use-case with a larger dataframe which I can't share, but can use to for timing different solutions):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': np.arange(datetime(2000,1,1), 
                                     datetime(2000,1,2), 
                                     timedelta(hours=3)).astype(datetime)})
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
                 Date
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00
1 2000-01-01 03:00:00
2 2000-01-01 06:00:00
3 2000-01-01 09:00:00
4 2000-01-01 12:00:00
5 2000-01-01 15:00:00
6 2000-01-01 18:00:00
7 2000-01-01 21:00:00
```

---

**Existing solution (too slow)**:

```
df['SinHour'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: np.sin((row.Date.hour + float(row.Date.minute) / 60.0) * np.pi / 12.0), 
    axis=1)
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
                 Date       SinHour
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00  0.000000e+00
1 2000-01-01 03:00:00  7.071068e-01
2 2000-01-01 06:00:00  1.000000e+00
3 2000-01-01 09:00:00  7.071068e-01
4 2000-01-01 12:00:00  1.224647e-16
5 2000-01-01 15:00:00 -7.071068e-01
6 2000-01-01 18:00:00 -1.000000e+00
7 2000-01-01 21:00:00 -7.071068e-01
```

I say this solution is too slow, because it computes every value in the column row-by-row. Of course, if this really is the only possibility, I'll have to settle for this. However, in the case of simpler functions, I've gotten huge speedups by using vectorized numpy functions, which I'm hoping will be possible in some way here too.

---

**Direction for desired solution (does not work):**

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
df = df.assign(
    SinHour=lambda data: np.sin((data.Date.hour + float(data.Date.minute) / 60.0)
    * np.pi / 12.0))
```

This is the direction I was hoping to go in, because it's no longer a row-by-row `apply`. However, it obviously doesn't work, because it can't access the `hour` and `minute` properties of the entire Date column at once in a "vectorized" manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You was really close, only need `.dt` for process `datetime`s `Series` and for cast [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = df.assign(SinHour=np.sin((df.Date.dt.hour + 
                              (df.Date.dt.minute).astype(float) / 60.0) * np.pi / 12.0)
               )
print(df)
                 Date       SinHour
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00  0.000000e+00
1 2000-01-01 03:00:00  7.071068e-01
2 2000-01-01 06:00:00  1.000000e+00
3 2000-01-01 09:00:00  7.071068e-01
4 2000-01-01 12:00:00  1.224647e-16
5 2000-01-01 15:00:00 -7.071068e-01
6 2000-01-01 18:00:00 -1.000000e+00
7 2000-01-01 21:00:00 -7.071068e-01
```

Comment: That worked fine indeed in my test case. I'll test it in my larger actual use-case later today and also comment here what kind of speed-up it provides there compared to the row-by-row solution in my question.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be faster ;)

Comment: I've written some code with a larger version of the example dataframe to time it, and your solution is indeed about 100 times faster (code and output may be interesting to edit into your answer: https://pastebin.com/KRFTXjVy). However, for my actual project, it does not provide a speedup. Could it be because I have to do the same thing as in the question in four slightly different variations (4 columns), which may be more efficient on a row-by-row basis? Or do you expect that should not make a significant difference?

Comment: Hmmm, in pandas obviously faster working functions row by row, so not sure if there is faster solution...